# How can I display an image overlay on all other images that are not currently being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this rendering code in my component (this renders an unordered list of `li` elements that each have their own image):

```
<div className="thumbnail-photos-wrapper">
  {spot.thumbnail_image_urls ? spot.thumbnail_image_urls.map(url => 
    <div className="thumbnail-image-wrapper">
      <img src={url} alt="Thumbnail photo" />
    </div>) : ''}
</div>
```

And when I'm hovering over one of these images, I'd like for the other images to be grayed out. I've found solutions about graying/blacking out the entire background, but that's not quite what I need; I'd only like the images that are not being hovered over grayed out.

I've also read that it's better to use states to interact with HTML elements in a JS/React app, however, I don't think that would work. If I had dynamic HTML classes in the render code above that depended on toggling the state, it would toggle all of the class names upon rerender (effectively changing all the class names for an image wrapper if the state was true or false; I only want to change the appearance of the non hovered images!).

I've also thought about doing something like this:

```
<div className="thumbnail-photos-wrapper">
  {spot.thumbnail_image_urls ? spot.thumbnail_image_urls.map(url => 
    <div className="thumbnail-image-wrapper">
      <div className="overlay-wrapper"></div>
      <img src={url} alt="Thumbnail photo" />
    </div>) : ''}
</div>
```

Where I have a separate div to hold the overlay. I was thinking that I could have this `overlay-wrapper` initially have a `display: none` (or something else to that effect), and then when the user hovers over an image, it becomes visible. However, I believe that this would also put an overlay on the hovered image, which is not what I want.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: From your description of desired behavior, one may conclude that when the pointer is not on top of either image, ***all*** of them should be grayed out. So accepted solution does not fulfill that part. If you're interested in react solution (that will not depend on dynamic classes and is pretty close to your attempt), you may check out  the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328773/11299053).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I've added a CSS `filter` with a short transition as an idea for a straightforward overlay, in place of changing `opacity`.

---

At the risk of oversimplifying this, you can use CSS negation to handle this task.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

> The **:not()** CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a
>   list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being
>   selected, it is known as the *negation pseudo-class*.

```css
.thumbnail-photos-wrapper:hover .thumbnail-image-wrapper:not(:hover) {
  filter: brightness(.33);
}

.thumbnail-image-wrapper {
  transition: filter 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* For styling puroses only — ignore */
.thumbnail-photos-wrapper { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-photos-wrapper">
  <div class="thumbnail-image-wrapper">
    <img src=http://placekitten.com/50/50 alt="Thumbnail photo" />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail-image-wrapper">
    <img src=http://placekitten.com/50/50 alt="Thumbnail photo" />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail-image-wrapper">
    <img src=http://placekitten.com/50/50 alt="Thumbnail photo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kenwc1v4/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the demo! I will give it a try!

Comment: Just curious, but is the `display: inline-block` just for your styling purposes? I'm guessing that's not part of the negation pseudo-class solution

Comment: @Karen For styling purposes only. You can ignore that part.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you! This was super helpful, I've never used negation pseudo-classes before so this was good to know. Another small question, if I needed to add a dark overlay over the image instead of just reducing opacity of the image, is it possible to do this in the css as well?

Comment: @Karen Glad to help.

Comment: @Karen If you can mark my answer as the chosen answer, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Oh! I'm not sure if you saw my earlier comment, before I accept it I was wondering if you had any advice on adding a dark overlay instead of just changing the opacity of the image

Comment: @Karen I missed your comment--sorry about that. Hopefully my update is helpful.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the update! I'll give that a quick try :D

Comment: Thanks again!! I was able to make some small tweaks with your solution and it looks awesome!